# Subset $A_{n,m}$ of $C[0,1]$ is nowhere dense

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the set of real-valued continuous function with domain [0,1], i.e., $C[0,1]$, with the uniform metric. Let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and define the set
$$
A_{n,m} = \{f\in C[0,1]: \left|\frac{f(x)-f(0.5)}{x-0.5}\right|\leq n \text{ for each }x\in[0,1] \text{ such that }0 < |x-0.5| < \frac{1}{m} \}.
$$
I have shown that $A_{n,m}$ is closed in $C[0,1]$. Now I need to show that $A_{n,m}$ is nowhere dense in $C[0,1]$, i.e., $A_{n,m}$ contains no open ball in $C[0,1]$. Any suggestions how to do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very rigorous, but here's a proof in pictures. Consider the following picture:

[image]

The black curve represents some $f \in A_{n,m}$. The shaded orange double-cone is given by
$$\left\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : \frac{|y - f(0.5)|}{|x - 0.5|} > n \right\},$$
and acts like a kind of no-go zone. If we consider the function value $f(0.5)$ to be fixed, this cone represents where the function cannot go locally around the point $x = 0.5$ in order to be in $A_{n,m}$.

We also have a blue band around the function. This is an $\varepsilon$-band: a continuous function $g$ lies within $\varepsilon$ distance of $f$ if and only if the graph of $g$ is contained in this band.

Now, can we find a function in this $\varepsilon$-band that is not in $A_{n,m}$? This is the negation of the assertion that the $\varepsilon$-ball centred at $f$ is contained in $A_{n,m}$.

Of course! We can just make a little spike like so:

[image]

As we consider larger and large $n$, the orange cone will shrink towards the vertical line. This is ok; we just put the spike closer to $0.5$.

As we consider smaller $\varepsilon > 0$, the $\varepsilon$-band will shrink towards the black curve. This is ok; we just make the spike shorter and steeper.

The $0 < |x - 0.5| < 1/m$ condition will constrict where this spike must occur, making it more difficult to find such an example as $m$ increases. This is ok; we can just make it arbitrarily close to $0.5$ once again.

Of course, this is just one continuous function. But a similar phenomenon will occur, due to continuity: the orange region will intersect the blue region around, and not directly above, the point $(0.5, f(0.5))$, so we can always spike the function.